# SQLSERV in PHP7 not Working

Tags: php, sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm attempting to connect with a Sybase database with PHP7 on Windows Server 2012 R2 using the sqlsrv PDO driver.  I've tried a number of connection strings - the following is the most direct connection string I've found that should be at least tossing me an error (an error from PHP) when accessing the page.  However, when I access the page it it tells me the page is not working (as in the PHP is not working).  PDO SQLSRV is active in my phpinfo().  The PHP Error I receive is:

> [18-Nov-2016 22:32:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.0\ext\php_wincache.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0

And many times in the same log file I am receiving the following error:

> [18-Nov-2016 22:31:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.0\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
>    in Unknown on line 0

This is all basically a straight-up install, so I'm surprised that it's tossing back errors about windows cache and mysql (when I'm not even attempting to access a mysql anything).  Any leads or information would be great.  Thank you for this forum!

```
 <?php

 try {

    $server_name = "MY\SERVER,1234";
    $database_name = "myDatabase";
    $username = "myUsername";
    $password = "myPassword";

    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server_name;database=$database_name", "$username", "$password");
    $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  

}

catch( PDOException $e ) {  

    die( "Error connecting to SQL Server" );   

}  

echo "Connected to SQL Server\n";  

?>
```

Comment: _it it tells me the page is not working_ in what way?

Comment: The 10.215.76.56 page isn’t working

10.215.76.56 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Check your server logs, the real error is in there

Comment: [18-Nov-2016 22:32:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.0\ext\php_wincache.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0 - Editing Main Post to Reflect New Information

Comment: If you don’t use the modules, disable those by commenting out corresponding lines in php.ini. If you need the modules, make sure there are corresponding `dll` files in the directory PHP searches for those files in.

Comment: This problem was solved using the information in this answered thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899323/sql-server-not-connecting-nor-tossing-errors